# Does “forked into the background, PID xxxx” means that i executed a malware?

Tags: command-line, security, malware

I am a complete newbie in Linux and I was given 2 executable malware files. I used the sudo ./filename command and a message popped up saying "Forked into background, PID XXXX". Does that mean I successfully executed the malware file?

I apologize if it's a dumb question to ask but I am entirely new to Linux :D

Comment: Are you able to share what `filename` was? Also, what happens when you type `fg` and press Enter? (The `fg` command will move a "background" job, if it exists, to the "foreground").

Comment: More context is needed. How do you know they were malware?  If you knew they were malware, why did you execute them?

Comment: Very likely yes. If `ps aux |grep XXXX` where XXXX is the PID you were shown shows you your malware executable, then it is running.

Comment: @CarlH it was a mini project for my class and was told to execute the malware files. I had to do a static and dynamic analysis of the files that were given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Longer answer: The "Forked into background, PID XXXX" message is unique to your malware.  I'm taking an educated guess that it probably [double forked](http://thelinuxjedi.blogspot.com/2014/02/why-use-double-fork-to-daemonize.html) so that it can continue running even if the parent PID exits.

Comment: Thank you and it was double forked! I was told to execute the malware files for my class and I was a little confused on whether it was executed or not.